# Get Windows Uptime/Load with PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008, whmcs

Our billing system supports network monitoring and shows uptime and load percentage, however, the PHP status script they provide says it is Linux only. Configuring PHP to work with Server 2008 is not an issue, but I don't know PHP. Would it be possible to manipulate this code to work on Windows?

```
<?php
/*
*************************************************************************
*                                                                       *
* WHMCompleteSolution - Client Management, Billing & Support System     *
* Copyright (c) 2007-2008 WHMCS. All Rights Reserved,                   *
* Release Date: 12th December 2008                                      *
* Version 3.8.1 Stable                                                  *
*                                                                       *
*************************************************************************
*                                                                       *
* Email: info@whmcs.com                                                 *
* Website: htttp://www.whmcs.com                                        *
*                                                                       *
*************************************************************************

This file can be uploaded to each of your linux web servers in order to
display current load and uptime statistics for the server in the Server
Status page of the WHMCS Client Area and Admin Area Homepage

*/

error_reporting(0);

if (ini_get('disable_functions')) {
    $disabled_funcs=array_map('trim',explode(',',ini_get('disable_functions')));
}

$action=$_GET["action"];

if ($action=="phpinfo") {
} else {
    $users[0]="Unavailable";
    $users[1]="--";
    $loadnow="Unavailable";
    $load15="--";
    $load30="--";
    if (in_array('exec',$disabled_funcs)) {
        $load=file_get_contents("/proc/loadavg");
        $load=explode(' ',$load);
        $loadnow=$load[0];
        $load15=$load[1];
        $load30=$load[2];
    } else {
        $reguptime=trim(exec("uptime"));
        if ($reguptime) {
            if (preg_match("/, *(\d) (users?), .*: (.*), (.*), (.*)/",$reguptime,$uptime)) {
                $users[0]=$uptime[1];
                $users[1]=$uptime[2];
                $loadnow=$uptime[3];
                $load15=$uptime[4];
                $load30=$uptime[5];
            }
        }
    }
    if (in_array('shell_exec',$disabled_funcs)) {
        $uptime_text=file_get_contents("/proc/uptime");
        $uptime=substr($uptime_text,0,strpos($uptime_text," "));
    } else {
        $uptime=shell_exec("cut -d. -f1 /proc/uptime");
    }
    $days=floor($uptime/60/60/24);
    $hours=str_pad($uptime/60/60%24,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $mins=str_pad($uptime/60%60,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $secs=str_pad($uptime%60,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $phpver=phpversion();
    if(function_exists("mysql_get_client_info()")) $mysqlver=mysql_get_client_info();
    if(function_exists("zend_version()")) $zendver=zend_version();
    echo "<load>$loadnow</load>\n";
    echo "<uptime>$days Days $hours:$mins:$secs</uptime>\n";
    echo "<phpver>$phpver</phpver>\n";
    echo "<mysqlver>$mysqlver</mysqlver>\n";
    echo "<zendver>$zendver</zendver>\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Not easily, no, seeing as it seems to be piping into `/proc/uptime` which AFAIK has no direct equivalent in Windows. I think you're better off trying to rewrite from scratch or looking for a Windows version

Comment: You'd basically have to rewrite it from scratch for Windows. This script uses /proc, which is a Linux/Unix-only thing. Windows undoubtedly provides interfaces for similar information, but they won't be as easy to access as /proc is.

Comment: I just found this information that mentions a way to do it, but would that work correctly to replace the nix code here? http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=101578&p=547861#p545386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version combines some of the ideas suggested here and some of my own into a file that *should* work roughly the same on both *nix and Windows. Also corrected a few glaring errors/lazy codes in the original.

Will **not** work on Windows if `exec()` is disabled. There is no way around this that I can see.

Let me know how you get on.

```
<?php

/*
*************************************************************************
*                                                                       *
* WHMCompleteSolution - Client Management, Billing & Support System     *
* Copyright (c) 2007-2008 WHMCS. All Rights Reserved,                   *
* Release Date: 12th December 2008                                      *
* Version 3.8.1 Stable                                                  *
*                                                                       *
*************************************************************************
*                                                                       *
* Email: info@whmcs.com                                                 *
* Website: htttp://www.whmcs.com                                        *
*                                                                       *
*************************************************************************

  Modified by DaveRandom, Sept 2011

This file can be uploaded to each of your linux/Windows web servers in
order to display current load and uptime statistics for the server in the
Server Status page of the WHMCS Client Area and Admin Area Homepage

*/

error_reporting(0);

if (ini_get('disable_functions')) {
  $disabled_funcs = array_map('trim',explode(',',ini_get('disable_functions')));
}

$action = (isset($_GET["action"])) ? $_GET["action"] : NULL;

if ($action == "phpinfo") {

  // Seems as though something is missing here - maybe phpinfo() ?

} else {

  // Stuff that works everywhere
  $phpver = phpversion();
  $mysqlver = (function_exists("mysql_get_client_info")) ? mysql_get_client_info() : '';
  $zendver = (function_exists("zend_version")) ? zend_version() : '';

  // Default values
  $users[0] = $loadnow = "Unavailable";
  $users[1] = $load15 = $load30 = "--";
  $uptime_str = '';

  if (strpos(strtolower(PHP_OS),'win') !== FALSE) {

    // For Windaz
    if (!in_array('exec',$disabled_funcs)) {

      set_time_limit(150); // 'systeminfo' command can take a while...

      $uptime = exec('systeminfo | find "System Up"');
      $parts = explode(':',$uptime);
      $parts = array_pop($parts);
      $parts = explode(',',trim($parts));
      foreach (array('days','hours','mins','secs') as $k => $v) {
        $parts[$k] = explode(' ',trim($parts[$k]));
        $$v = ($k) ? str_pad(array_shift($parts[$k]),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT) : array_shift($parts[$k]);
      }
      $uptime_str = "$days Days $hours:$mins:$secs";

      exec('typeperf -sc 1 "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time"',$result);
      for ($i = 0; trim($result[$i]) == ''; $i++) continue;
      $parts = explode(',',$result[++$i]);
      $loadnow = (is_numeric($loadnow = trim(trim(array_pop($parts)),'"\''))) ? $loadnow : 'Unavailable';

    }

  } else {

    // For *nix

    if (in_array('exec',$disabled_funcs)) {
      $load = file_get_contents("/proc/loadavg");
      $load = explode(' ',$load);
      $loadnow = $load[0];
      $load15 = $load[1];
      $load30 = $load[2];
    } else if (($reguptime = trim(exec("uptime"))) && preg_match("/, *(\\d) (users?), .*: (.*), (.*), (.*)/",$reguptime,$uptime)) {
      $users[0] = $uptime[1];
      $users[1] = $uptime[2];
      $loadnow = $uptime[3];
      $load15 = $uptime[4];
      $load30 = $uptime[5];
    }
    if (in_array('shell_exec',$disabled_funcs)) {
      $uptime_text = file_get_contents("/proc/uptime");
      $uptime = substr($uptime_text,0,strpos($uptime_text," "));
    } else {
      $uptime = shell_exec("cut -d. -f1 /proc/uptime");
    }
    $days = floor($uptime/60/60/24);
    $hours = str_pad($uptime/60/60%24,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $mins = str_pad($uptime/60%60,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $secs = str_pad($uptime%60,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $uptime_str = "$days Days $hours:$mins:$secs";

  }

  echo "<load>$loadnow</load>\n";
  echo "<uptime>$uptime_str</uptime>\n";
  echo "<phpver>$phpver</phpver>\n";
  echo "<mysqlver>$mysqlver</mysqlver>\n";
  echo "<zendver>$zendver</zendver>\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For uptime, you can do an `exec()` call against `systeminfo | find "System Up"` and then process the output.

For load, you can run `wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path Win32_Processor get LoadPercentage`, though this only gets the current CPU load and not the historical averages.

At any rate, you will have to detect the operating system (see [`PHP_OS`](http://php.net/manual/function.php-uname.php)) and run the correct commands for the system your script is running on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following on a windows box to get the system uptime in a string:

```
$uptimeData = shell_exec('systeminfo | find "Time:"');
```

If you want the data in a different format you'll probably need to use a regex, but it looks like your script is just dumping the information to an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo shell_exec("systeminfo |find 'Up Time'");?>
```

But you need to set php max execution time at least to 120 (execution of this command takes some time)

Comment: another way for obtaining the uptime is ````filemtime('c:/pagefile.sys')````, with the upside of being much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

try This :

Code : https://miladworkshop.ir/paste/Uzype9

```
<?php
/*
    This Code Create By Milad Maldar ( miladworkshop )
    Website     : https://miladworkshop.ir
    Telegram    : @miladworkshop
*/

function service_uptime()
{
    $uptime_sys     = exec('net statistics server | find "Statistics since"');
    $uptime_sys     = str_replace("Statistics since ", "", $uptime_sys);

    $uptime_dte     = exec('date | find "The current date is:"');
    $uptime_dte     = str_replace("The current date is: Sat ", "", $uptime_dte);
    $uptime_dte     = explode("/", $uptime_dte);

    $uptime_tme     = exec('time | find "The current time is:"');
    $uptime_tme     = str_replace("The current time is: ", "", $uptime_tme);
    $uptime_tme     = explode(":", $uptime_tme);

    $uptime_date    = explode("/", $uptime_sys);
    $uptime_time    = explode(":", $uptime_sys);

    $system_time    = strtotime("{$uptime_dte[2]}-{$uptime_dte[0]}-{$uptime_dte[1]} {$uptime_tme[0]}:{$uptime_tme[1]}:{$uptime_tme[2]}");

    $y              = substr($uptime_date[2], 0, 4);
    $m              = ($uptime_date[0] < 10) ? "0". $uptime_date[0] : $uptime_date[0];
    $d              = ($uptime_date[1] < 10) ? "0". $uptime_date[1] : $uptime_date[1];
    $i              = ($uptime_time[1] < 10) ? "0". $uptime_time[1] : $uptime_time[1];
    $h              = (substr($uptime_time[0], strpos($uptime_time[0], "{$y} ") + 5) < 10) ? "0". substr($uptime_time[0], strpos($uptime_time[0], "{$y} ") + 5) : substr($uptime_time[0], strpos($uptime_time[0], "{$y} ") + 5);

    if (substr($uptime_sys, -2) == "PM")
    {
        $h = str_replace("01", "13", $h);
        $h = str_replace("02", "14", $h);
        $h = str_replace("03", "15", $h);
        $h = str_replace("04", "16", $h);
        $h = str_replace("05", "17", $h);
        $h = str_replace("06", "18", $h);
        $h = str_replace("07", "19", $h);
        $h = str_replace("08", "20", $h);
        $h = str_replace("09", "21", $h);
        $h = str_replace("10", "22", $h);
        $h = str_replace("11", "23", $h);
        $h = str_replace("12", "00", $h);
    }

    $up                 = strtotime("{$y}-{$m}-{$d} {$h}:{$i}:00");

    $string             = "";
    $seconds            = $system_time - $up;

    $days               = intval(intval($seconds) / (3600*24));
    $hours              = (intval($seconds) / 3600) % 24;
    $minutes            = (intval($seconds) / 60) % 60;
    $seconds            = (intval($seconds)) % 60;

    if($days> 0)        { $string .= "{$days} days ";       }
    if($hours > 0)      { $string .= "{$hours} hours ";         }
    if($minutes > 0)    { $string .= "{$minutes} minutes ";     }
    if ($seconds > 0)   { $string .= "{$seconds} seconds";  }

    return $string;
}

echo service_uptime();
?>
```